# How to store a List in Hive (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I am trying to store and fetch a list using `Hive` in Flutter, however I get a range error.

```
    int steps = 0;
    List<int> stepCountList = List(7);
    var time = DateTime.now();

   // This is my method for a listener that updates when it detects a change,
    void _onData(int newValue) async {
    fetchSteps();
    steps = stepCountList[time.weekday] ?? 0;
    stepDivider += newValue;
    stepCountList.insert(time.weekday - 1, steps);
     moneyLottoBox.put('stepCountList', stepCountList);
  }

 void fetchSteps() {
    stepCountList = moneyLottoBox.get('stepCountList');
    if (stepCountList == null) {
      moneyLottoBox.put('stepCountList', <int>[7]);
      stepCountList = moneyLottoBox.get('stepCountList');
    }
  }
// I create my MoneyLotto box here,
var moneyLottoBox = Hive.box('moneyLottoBox');
Future<void> main async {
 moneyLottoBox = await Hive.openBox('box');
}
```

Today being Saturday for me, the value of `time.weekday` for me is 6, however it shows me the error when I try to `print(stepCountList[6])`

```
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 6
```

Comment: How are you printing the `List`? Just asking, shouldn't `List` `length` be 7 considering 0 to 6 inclusive ?

Comment: It prints this error when I print stepCountList[6]

Comment: Ok, `print` its length first. `print(stepCountList.length)`.

Comment: It prints the length as 1

Comment: `stepCountList = moneyLottoBox.get('stepCountList', defaultValue: <int>[6]);` This is overwriting the initial `List`

Comment: Should I remove the defaultValue?

Comment: Try removing.  What is `moneyLottoBox` ?

Comment: So when I try to replace now.weekday with 0, it works flawlessly but not with at the index I want to store it at :(

Comment: When you initially create `moneyLottoBox ` and put `stepCountList ` , what is the length of that `List` ?

Comment: I only call stepCountList in my onData method, and the value is the same as my current list

Comment: Try adding the `stepCountList` with `length 7 ` in `moneyLottoBox`  when you first create `moneyLottoBox`.

Comment: I updated my question, didn't work

Comment: Where do you create `moneyLottoBox` ? At the time of creation itself add a `stepCountList` of `length` 7.

Comment: I updated my question, could you show a programmatic example?

Comment: Added below. Try and see if it works or gives any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `insert()` method on fixed length List, by fixed length I mean  when you declare it this way `List<int> stepCountList = List(7);`
Edited the code, now it should work

```
void _onData(int newValue) async {
    fetchSteps();
    steps = stepCountList[time.weekday] ?? 0;
    stepDivider += newValue;
    //stepCountList.insert(time.weekday - 1, steps);this is not correct
    stepCountList[time.weekday -1] = steps; // this should be the approach
     moneyLottoBox.put('stepCountList', stepCountList);
  }


void fetchSteps() {
    stepCountList = moneyLottoBox.get('stepCountList');
    if (stepCountList == null) {
     /* moneyLottoBox.put('stepCountList', <int>[7]); this statement is the 
reason for your error because your are storing a growable list instead of fixed list in the hive */

moneyLottoBox.put('stepCountList', List<int>(7));// try this instead 
// or u can use this moneyLottoBox.put('stepCountList', stepCountList);
      stepCountList = moneyLottoBox.get('stepCountList');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive box has methods like: `put(dynamic key, E value)`, `putAll(Map<dynamic, E> entries)` and `putAt(int index, E value)`. For example, I used `putAt()` to update entry at the specific key.

For adding with auto-increment key, you want to use `add(E value)` or to add a list - `addAll(Iterable<E> values)`.

And when I wanted to delete all data in the box, I used `clear()`, like so:

```
await _booksBox.clear();
```

And this method is for getting all the entries from the database:

```
List<Book> getAllBooks() {
  return _booksBox.values.map(_bookFromDb).toList();
}
```

A complete Hive db class is from the [tutorial](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/flutter-list-details-app-with-cubits-hooks-and-hive-database-2e87be09b580).