# How To Store List in Hive? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, hive

I am building an application for experience. I am trying to store list in hive. So, can anyone explain how can I store list in hive?

In below list, all data are stored. I want to store these data in hive through all category list.

```
List<CategoryModel> allcategorylist =[]
```

Comment: Please check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62609037/how-to-store-a-list-in-hive-flutter

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to modify your **CategoryModel** class like this-

```
part 'category_model.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0, adapterName: "CategoryAdapter")
class CategoryModel{

  @HiveField(0)
  final String exampleField1; 

  @HiveField(1)
  final String exampleField2;

  CategoryModel({required this.exampleField1, required this.exampleField2});
}
```

After that , make sure you added those dependencies in your `pubspec.yaml` file

```
dependencies:
  hive: ^2.2.3
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  hive_generator: ^1.1.3
  build_runner: ^[latest version]
```

**Now run this command in your terminal**

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

After successfully run this command `hive_generator` create a adapter named **CategoryAdapter**, you will find this class in `category_model.g.dart` file.

Now modify your `main.dart` file like this

```
  void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(WallpaperAdapter());

  runApp(MyApp());
  }
```

Now your configuration is ready for store the custom object

**Store CategoryModel object:**

```
  const key = 'categoryKey';
  final box = await Hive.openBox<List>('categoryList');

  final newCategory = CategoryModel(
    exampleField1: "This is example field1", 
    exampleField2: "This is example field2",

  );

  List<CategoryModel> categoryList = [];
 
  categoryList.add(newCategory);

  await box.put(key, notificationList);
```

**Fetch data:**

```
  final categoryList = box.get(key, defaultValue: []) ?? [];
  print(categoryList);
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you gone through the [documentation](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/basics/read_write)?

Here is an example from the documentation.

```dart
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

void main() async {
  var box = await Hive.openBox('someBox');

  var initialList = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  box.put('myList', initialList);

  var myList = box.get('myList');
  myList[0] = 'd';

  print(initialList[0]); // d
}
```

Comment: add this one also  await Hive.initFlutter();  in main

Comment: where the d came from?

Comment: @JohnJoe It was added previously  Just Kidding

Comment: On the linked page the source code doesn't show up - but you can see it if you click "edit on github".  https://github.com/hivedb/docs/blob/master/basics/read_write.md
The fact that in the code above, initialList and myList actually refer to the same object is quite surprising and not explained very well unless you're very experienced.

Comment: If box is a global variable instead of being inside main, any piece of code anywhere in the app that reads the 'myList' list gets a reference to the same list  - hence if one piece of code changes the list, all the other pieces of code will see that change - even though it hasn't been written back to the database.